# Parseval's Theorem

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

The Fourier transform $\tilde f(k)$ of a function $f(x)$ is defined as $$\tilde f(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ikx}f(x)dx $$ and the correlation $h(x)$ between two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is defined by $$h(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f(x))^*g(x+y)dy $$ where * denotes a complex conjugate.

In the first part of the question, I was asked to prove that  $\tilde h(k)=((\tilde f(k))^* \tilde g(k)
$, which I was able to do.

Then, I was asked to use this result $\tilde h(k)=((\tilde f(k))^* \tilde g(k)$ to prove Parseval's theorem $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|^2dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\tilde f(k)|^2 dk$$ How can I go about it?

Comment: Just FYI, this result for Fourier transforms is more properly known as Plancherel's Theorem, whereas Parseval's Theorem refers to the corresponding result for Fourier *series*, even though it is extremely common among physicists and engineers to refer to both theorems as Parseval's. /endpedant

Comment: I assume, that the definition of correlation should be $h(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty {(f(x))}^*g(x+y) dx$.

Comment: In the second integral it should be $(f(y))^{*}$ not $(f(x))^{*}$.

Answer (score 2):

Set $g = f$ and calculate
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(x)|^2dx & = & h(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty\tilde{h}(k) e^{ik0} dk = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty {(\tilde{f}(k))}^* \tilde{f}(k) dk \\
& = & \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\tilde{f}(k)|^2 dk,
\end{eqnarray}
that is the desired result.

Comment: The proof applies Fourier inversion theorem, that is true at least if $h \in \mathscr{S}_n$, that is, if $h$ is a test function that is smooth and rapidly decreasing. In addition all other improper Riemann-integrals of the first kind in the calculation have also to exist

Comment: With reference to this equation: $h(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f(x))^*g(x+y)dy $: is setting x=0 a sufficient condition for g = f?